# Why won't 'this' work?

Tags: jquery

Link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TungstenNo74/nCCMP/2/

Probably a noob question, but I've been searching for a while and just cannot figure it out.

I am trying to display a bar graph for an arbitrary number of scores.  I was thinking I'd initialize a 'bar' object for each score and then build the bar for it.

I can't figure out how to animate each individual bar rather than the whole .class (which, right now is set to '.test')

```
function bar(score, index,selector) {
this.score = score;
this.barHeight = score * 6;
}

bar.prototype.makeBar = function () {
    $('#plot').append('<div class=test></div>');
};

bar.prototype.growBar = function () {
    //$('.test').animate({ //This works, but it animates all of my bars...
        $(this).animate({ //Why doesn't 'this' work?
        'height': this.barHeight
    }, 'slow', function () {});
};

var test = new bar(24, 0,'plot');   //Isn't this what 'this' refers to?
test.makeBar();
test.growBar();
```

Comment: This refers to the current element being targeted. Here this does not point to any element  just an anonymous function.

Comment: @karthikr: No, `this` refers to the object `test` or `test2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

becuse in your full fiddle example you can see that `this` is not an actual DOM element that jQuery could animate.

```
var plotHeight = $('#plot').css('height');

function bar(score, index) {
    this.score = score;
    this.index = index;
    this.barHeight = score * 6;
}

bar.prototype.makeBar = function () {
    $('#plot').append('<div class=test></div>');
};
bar.prototype.growBar = function () {
    //$('.test').animate({
    $(this).animate({ //Why doesn't 'this' work?
        'height': this.barHeight
    }, 'slow', function () {});
};

var test = new bar(24, 0); //score gives height, index does nothing... yet
test.makeBar();
test.growBar();

var test2 = new bar(15, 2); // This is just an object of type bar and does not hold a jQuery element to be animated.
test2.makeBar();
test2.growBar();
```

you could do something like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/nCCMP/3/

```
var plotHeight = $('#plot').css('height');

function bar(score, index,selector) {
    this.score = score;
    this.index = index;
    this.barHeight = score * 6;
    this.container = $(selector); // here is the DOM element
}

bar.prototype.makeBar = function () {
    $('#plot').append('<div class=test></div>');
};
bar.prototype.growBar = function () {
    //$('.test').animate({
    $(this.container).animate({ //Now it will animate the element.
        'height': this.barHeight
    }, 'slow', function () {});
};

var test = new bar(24, 0,'#plot'); 
test.makeBar();
test.growBar();

var test2 = new bar(15, 2,'#plot');
test2.makeBar();
test2.growBar();
```

**EDIT:**

```
I would try to write a jQuery plugin for that, it would probably start something like that:

(function ($) {
    $.fn.scoreBar = function (options) {
        var defaultVal = {
            score,: 0,
            index: '0'
        };

        var obj = $.extend(defaultVal, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var selObject = $(this);
            selObject.animate({ 'height': this.barHeight }, 'slow', function () {});
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then you call it like that:

```
$('#ScoreBarContainer').scoreBar({score=24,index=0});
```

Comment: This is just animating the container for the bars animate rather than the bars themself.  I'll see if I can adapt it...

Comment: sorry if i have misunderstood but i thought that this was what you wanted to animate as this was the only html DOM element in your example.

Comment: I guess I still need to get my head wrapped around the DOM.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I think I get the problem: nothing is being animated with 'this' because this is pointing to a 'bar' which is a javascript object, not part of the DOM.
So, then, how would I reference the appended div as a DOM element?  I can think of a couple ways but they seem kind of inefficient.  Is there something built in that I don't know about?

Comment: if you would like this to referance the jQuery ekement representing the DOM element the best way would be to make the Bar class be a plugin of jQuery .. try this as a starter example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291290/How-To-Write-Plugin-in-jQuery

Comment: See my edit i have added an example to writing a jquery plugin.